# Is it okay to use tables for post formatting?

Tags: html, css

Basically I'm making a feature to post on my site, and I just wanted your guys' opinions: do you think it's okay to use a table to format the post (aligning the profile picture and the post? If not, what do you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tables should never be used for anything besides tabular data.

I would suggest reading into inline-block

Answer (score 3):

If it's not tabular data, then **no**. If it can be done with divs, then do it with divs :)

Comment: Just about everything can be done with divs, that doesn't mean it's the right tag for the job.  There isn't enough information in the OP to suggest anything in particular.

Comment: Let me rephrase; done CONVENIENTLY with divs? :)